# I want to add active class to both the navigation link dropdown and the option selected from that dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so there are multiple dropdown link in my navigation bar, so i want to add active class to both to the dropdown link and the option selected form that dropdown. (only javascript and jquery solution required)

index.html ( so i want to add the active class to meters button and option selected from the meters dropdown at the same time)

```
 <div class="topnav1" id="myTopnav1" >
        <!-- overview button -->
          <div class="dropdown1" >
            <button  id="overview-button" class="dropbtn1 over_active">Overview 
            </button>
          </div>
            <!-- energy meters start-->
          <div class="dropdown1" >
            <button id="btn_em" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_em')" class="dropbtn1">Meters 
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_em">
                <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
            </div>
          </div> 
          <!-- energy meters ends-->
          <!-- inverters start-->
          <div class="dropdown1">
            <button  id="btn_inv" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inv')" class="dropbtn1">Inverters 
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inv">
                <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- inverters ends-->
          <!-- inverter manager starts-->
          <div class="dropdown1">
            <button  id="btn_inm" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inm')" class="dropbtn1">Inverter Manager 
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inm">
                <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
            </div>
          </div>


          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      </div>
```

main.js

```
$('.dropbtn1, .dropnav-container ').click(function (e) {

                $('.dropbtn1, .dropnav-container ').removeClass('over_active');

                var $parent = $(this);
                if (!$parent.hasClass('over_active')) {
                    $parent.addClass('over_active');
                }
                var make_active = $('.dropnav-container');
                var make_active1 = $(`#btn_${dev_type}`);
                if(make_active.hasClass('over_active')){
                  make_active1.addClass('over_active');
                }

                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

style.css (this is the css for the navigation bar i want the solution in javacript and jquery)

```
.topnav1 {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }

  /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
  .topnav1 a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
  }


  .topnav-right1 {
    float: right;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    .topnav-right1 {
        float: left;
      } 
  }

  .para-active{
    background-color: #4F7ADA !important;
    color: black !important;
  }

  .para-active button{
      color: white !important;
  }

  /* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
  .active1 {
    color: black !important;
  }

  /* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
  .topnav1 .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown1 {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  }

  /* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
  .dropdown1 .dropbtn1 {
    font-size: 10px; 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
  }

  /* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
  .dropdown-content1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 96px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
 .mystyle{
   display: block;
 }
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: where exactly do you want the active class ? can you put them in your example ?

Comment: i have add the code which i have tried @HappyCoding

Comment: i want to add active class in all the links and button when they are clicked @FrançoisHuppé

Comment: @lalitkumar, are you stuck at some point? what is the issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

//when button is clicked

```
$('.dropbtn1').click(function (e) {

    $('.dropbtn1, .dropnav-container ').removeClass('over_active');

    $(this).addClass('over_active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

// when drop down is clicked

```
$('.dropnav-container').click(function (e) {

    $('.dropbtn1, .dropnav-container ').removeClass('over_active');

    $(this).addClass('over_active');

    $(this).parent().parent().find('.dropbtn1').addClass('over_active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: it is adding active class to all the options when i click dropdown link @HappyCoding

Comment: so if drop down is clicked then which option should be highlighted?

Comment: when the user is clicking the drop down for the first time no option should be highlighted. and when the user click on drop down it should apply the active class to dropdown first and then when ever the user select any option from that drop down the active class should be applied to that option also. @HappyCoding

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```css
.topnav1 {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }

  /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
  .topnav1 a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
  }


  .topnav-right1 {
    float: right;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    .topnav-right1 {
        float: left;
      } 
  }

  .para-active{
    background-color: #4F7ADA !important;
    color: black !important;
  }

  .para-active button{
      color: white !important;
  }

  /* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
  .active1 {
    color: black !important;
  }

  /* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
  .topnav1 .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown1 {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  }

  /* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
  .dropdown1 .dropbtn1 {
    font-size: 10px; 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
  }

  /* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
  .dropdown-content1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 96px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
 .mystyle{
   display: block;
 }
 .dropnav-container{
    display:block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav1" id="myTopnav1" >
        <!-- overview button -->
          <div class="dropdown1" >
            <button  id="overview-button" class="dropbtn1 over_active">Overview 
            </button>
          </div>
            <!-- energy meters start-->
          <div class="dropdown1" >
            <button id="btn_em" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_em')" class="dropbtn1">Meters 
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_em">
                <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
            </div>
          </div> 
          <!-- energy meters ends-->
          <!-- inverters start-->
          <div class="dropdown1">
            <button  id="btn_inv" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inv')" class="dropbtn1">Inverters 
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inv">
                <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- inverters ends-->
          <!-- inverter manager starts-->
          <div class="dropdown1">
            <button  id="btn_inm" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inm')" class="dropbtn1">Inverter Manager 
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inm">
                <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
                <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
            </div>
          </div>


          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      </div>
<script>
function toggleDropDown(div){
  $('#'+div).toggle();
  $('#'+div).toggleClass('para-active'); //add class which you want to.
  $('#'+div).parent().find('button').toggleClass('para-active'); //add class which you want to.
  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do changes is `css` on `hover` of dropdown that class will be active i.e :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav1");
  if (x.className === "topnav1") {
    x.className += " responsive1";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav1";
  }
}

function toggleDropDown(myid) {
  closeMenus(myid);
  var element = document.getElementById(myid);
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");  
}

function closeMenus(currentId) {
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content1");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('mystyle') && openDropdown.id !== currentId) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove('mystyle');
    }
  }
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn1')) {
    closeMenus();
  }
}
```

```css
topnav1 {
  background-color: blue !important;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav1 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
}

.topnav-right1 {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .topnav-right1 {
    float: left;
  }
}

.para-active {
  background-color: #4F7ADA !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.para-active button {
  color: white !important;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.active1 {
  color: black !important;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav1 .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown1 {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}


/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */

.dropdown1 .dropbtn1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
}


/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 96px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.mystyle {
  display: block;
}
/*add this css to button*/
.dropbtn1:hover,.dropbtn1:focus{
color:red;/*add any color*/

}
/*drop down menu*/
.dropnav-container:hover,.dropnav-container:focus{
color:red;/*add any color*/

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav1" id="myTopnav1">
  <!-- overview button -->
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="overview-button" class="dropbtn1 over_active">Overview 
            </button>
  </div>
  <!-- energy meters start-->
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_em" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_em')" class="dropbtn1">Meters 
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_em">
      <label class="dropnav-container">one</label><br/>
      <label class="dropnav-container">one</label><br/>
      <label class="dropnav-container">one</label><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- energy meters ends-->
  <!-- inverters start-->
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_inv" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inv')" class="dropbtn1">Inverters 
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inv">
      <label class="dropnav-container">two</label><br/>
      <label class="dropnav-container">two</label><br/>
      <label class="dropnav-container">two</label><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- inverters ends-->
  <!-- inverter manager starts-->
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_inm" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inm')" class="dropbtn1">Inverter Manager 
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inm">
      <label class="dropnav-container">three</label><br/>
      <label class="dropnav-container">three</label><br/>
      <label class="dropnav-container">three</label><br/>
    </div>
  </div>


  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```